# How to submit only one item from a list

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a list of objects and i want to be able to do is when a user clicks the  button associated with an item from the list, that item is displayed in another view

```
 @model VitalBits_2._0.Models.VitalBitListModel
<html>
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th style="align-content:center">
                Title
            </th>
            <th style="align-content:center">
                Vital Bit Type
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>

        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.VitalBitList.Count; i++)
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("PopulateEdit_Create", "Configuration", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <tr>
                    <td style="align-content:center">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].ID)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].Title)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].Title)
                    </td>
                    <td style="align-content:center">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].Message)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].Message)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].IsActive)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].IsPriority)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].BitType)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].Created)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].CreatedBy)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].LastModified)
                        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.VitalBitList[i].LastModifiedBy)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="submit">Edit</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>

    <div id="CreateEdit"></div>

</body>
```

This is how my code currently stands but i am currently getting my constructor values instead of the item selected

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult PopulateEdit_Create(VitalBit selectedItem) {
        DataFactory dataFactory = new DataFactory(); 

       //Logic and stuff

        return View("~/Views/Configuration/Create_Edit.cshtml", selectedItem);
    }
```

In other words can i only submit one item to my controller at a time, or do i have to do it in a different way?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Because you are creating a new object (`VitalBit newViewModel = new VitalBit();`). Simply use the parameter of your action method `selectedItem`

Comment: Oops, yeah that was wrong so i fixed it, but the issue is still the same. The parameter selectedItem is the one not getting the values

Comment: If all you are doing is navigating to a new page based on a click then use an anchor instead of a form post.

Comment: There is logic in the controller i just left it out for brevity, as its the parameter i'm having trouble with, not the logic

Comment: If it is to navigate to an EDIT screen (Edit GET Action), Why you need a form submit ? Just pass the Id via a link

Comment: That would be a lot easier, thank you. Just for the sake of learning, is there a way to pass only one item from a list back to the controller? Or was what i was trying to do impossible?

Comment: It is possible. Just change the edit button to an anhor tag and pass the Id of the item (the current item in the loop) via querystring.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again